# Issue while comparing two strings which are nil - Objective C

Tags: objective-c, null, nsstring

I am comparing two strings.

The problem is when my both strings are `nil`. I don't know when both strings comes `nil` then why control goes in `success` block.

I am using this code to compare strings:

```
  if(![oldString isEqualToString:newString]) 
        {
            //in case both are nil control reaches here
            needToShowPopup = YES;
            break;
        }
```

**Edit**: I want if only both strings are different then only my control will go inside `if statement`. My condition is failing when both are `nil`

Comment: There are 4 possibilities. 1) Both strings are non-nil, 2) Both are `nil`, 3) only `oldString` is `nil`, 4) only `newString` is `nil`. Update your question with how you wish to handle all 4 cases.

Comment: Your edit doesn't help. Clearly explain how you wish to handle all 4 cases. Simply stating that you wish to "handle" it doesn't tell us how.

Comment: @rmaddy is it good now ?

Comment: Note that when `oldString` is `nil`, the call to `isEqualToString` will always return 0. In fact, every method called on a `nil` object is guaranteed to return 0.

Comment: You got downvoted because it would have taken you 30 seconds to see what [oldstring isEqualToStringLnewString] evalutated to when the string are null by just tweaking and running code. Then you would have seen it evaluates to false. Then you should have known that !false is true. Hence with a couple of minutes debugging effort there should have been no need for a question in the first place.

Answer (score 6):

If you want the `if` condition to only be evaluated when both strings are not `nil` then you can do:

```
if (oldString && newString && ![oldString isEqualToString:newString]) {
    // both strings are set but they are not the same
}
```

The code you have will enter the `if` statement if `oldString` is `nil` regardless of the value of `newString`.

Comment: To clarify here (bringing this in from a comment above so @RahulMishra sees it): any message sent to `nil` always returns `0` or its equivalent (`0.0`, `nil`, `NO`, etc.). When you ask `[oldString isEqualToString:...]`, it doesn't matter what the second parameter is; this will always return `NO`. This leads to counterintuitive things like `[nil isEqual:nil] == NO`.

Answer (score 1):

I *think* you are saying that you want the equivalent of `[nil isEqualToString:nil]` returning true. If that is the case your `if` can be written:

```
if(oldString ? ![oldString isEqualToString:newString] : newString)
```

Alternatively if you don't want the `if` to execute if either or both values are `nil` then your `if` can be written:

```
if(oldString && newString && ![oldString isEqualToString:newString])
```

HTH

Comment: In the first option, shouldn't it be `!newString` to properly detect that both strings are nil?

Comment: @AurelienPorte - The OP wants the body of the `if` to evaluate if the two strings are *different*. The OP's original code fails in the `nil`/`nil` because the subexpression `[nil isEqualToString:nil]` evaluates to false and so comple expression `![nil isEqualToString:nil]` evaluates to true and the OP wants false in this case. The first option does produce false for `nil`/`nil`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I do it

```
if(oldString == newString || [oldString isEqualToString:newString]) {
   // strings are the same
}
```

The first check `oldString == newString` compares the pointers. Either both pointers are the same memory address so they must by definition be equal, or both pointers are `nil`, so also equal

If that fails, then we call `[oldString isEqualToString:newString]`, which compares the string contents. If either side is nil, then this will return false which is what we want, but if both sides are nil it will have caught it in the previous check and we won't get here :-)

Answer (score -2):

```
If (oldstring!=null)
{
Your code...
}
```